# Error: The field RecurrenceEndDateOnly is invalid

Tags: soql, data-loader, error

Doing a mass update on some tasks and came across this error. I understand the RecurrenceEndDateOnly field is used for recurring tasks, so this question is more about the error than the field. Has anyone encountered this and if so what's a good fix?

Notes:

- I have admin
- I am using Data Loader (v37) to modify these records
- The update I'm performing has 2 fields mapped: `ID`, `Latest_Status_Change_Time__c`
- The file used has 3 columns: `ID`, `Latest_Status_Change_Time__c`, `CreatedDate`
- When I edit the task (the exact same update I would perform via data loader) through SF UI, I have no issue.
- We've seen this issue when we use process builder (or any other Salesforce workflow tool) to process a task
- The isRecurrence value for all of these records is `FALSE`
- The RecurrenceEndDateOnly field for all of these records is populated.
- Attempting to mass update the RecurrenceEndDateOnly field results in the same error.

I believe last time we ran into this issue I wrote a small execute anon script to iterate through the tasks and null the value.

Other than that, I'm considering exporting all of these tasks then inserting them without the RecurrenceEndDateOnly then deleting the ones exported.

I wouldn't mind some feedback on those solutions. I would also like to know how to stop this from happening in the future. I'm assuming this is a default users have configured.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure why dataloader cannot modify the field, but I was able to null out ark the values with an execute anonymous script.

```
List<task> taskList = new List<task>();
For(task taskVar :[select Id, recurrenceEndDateOnly from task where id in (add list of ids here)]){
taskVar.recurrenceEndDatOnly = null;
taskList.add(taskVar);}
Update taskList;
```

This will iterate through the list and clear out the value. I found I had to search by id because the recurrenceEndDateOnly can't be used in a where clause.

Comment: Leaving this answer to help anyone else that might need a work around. I don't think it answers my original question of why dataloader cannot modify the field but UI and apex can.